# Google Cloud Function error (Permission Denied) when updating IoT device configs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, what I need to do is basically when I change a value in Google Cloud Firestore, it'll trigger a Cloud Function to send this value to an IoT device. Here's what I've done:

1. I created a service account for this specific task. I gave it the following permissions:

   1. cloudiot.admin (for managing Google Cloud IoT devices)
   2. firebase.sdkAdminServiceAgent (for managing Firestore)
   3. Owner (temporary one, for debugging purposes)
2. I created an IoT device registry, and a device on this registry.
3. Created the cloud function, and set its service account as the one I created.

Here's the code for the cloud function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const iot = require("@google-cloud/iot");

const app = admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = app.firestore();
const client = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient();

firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

exports.deviceConfigs = functions.firestore
  .document("device-configs/{device}")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const deviceId = context.params.device;

    if (!change.after.exists) {
      functions.logger.error(`Device configurations removed for ${deviceId}`);
      return;
    }
    const config = change.after.data();

    const formattedName = client.devicePath(
      process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
      functions.config().iot.core.region,
      functions.config().iot.core.registry,
      deviceId
    );

    const request = {
      name: formattedName,
      binaryData: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(config)).toString("base64"),
    };  

    await client.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(request);
  });
```

So then, whenever I write on a document inside the collection "device-configs", the function will be triggered, and an autheticated request should be sent to the IoT device, informing a configuration change. It's authenticated because it's running directly from the google backend, as it is a cloud function, so it should be authenticated as the service account I made.

However, everytime it gets triggered it fails on the last line. Here's the error:

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

I honestly don't know what to do anymore. I've tried running it locally on an emulator, using the service key as authentication, but it still returns the same error. I've tried to find a way to log all the api requests that Google Cloud receives, to see if the authentication is present on the header, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

### Edit

Ok, I don't know if it may help, but I also have this other Cloud Function that listens for new messages on a PubSub topic and updates the Firestore database accordingly. This function is working fine. Here's the code:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const iot = require("@google-cloud/iot");

const app = admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = app.firestore();
const client = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient();

firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

exports.deviceState = functions.pubsub
  .topic("device-events")
  .onPublish(async (message) => {
    functions.logger.warn("Mensagem:", { message });
    const deviceId = message.attributes.deviceId;
    const deviceRef = firestore.doc(`device-state/${deviceId}`);

    try {
      await deviceRef.update({
        state: message.json,
        online: true,
      });
      functions.logger.log("Device updated successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      functions.logger.error(error);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ok, solution found!

Basically, make sure to tripple, quadrupple check the project and registry names! Check character by character. This thing took me embarassingly 4 days to solve.

Answer (score 1):

const app = admin.initializeApp();

Change this to

```
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://YOURPROJECTNAME.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Download ServiceAccountKey from firebase add this in the same folder where this file is there and add your database url

Comment: Thank you Tasnuva. Well, since I'm not using a real time DB I didn't specify the databaseURL. It returned the same error

Comment: create a firestore db in firebase account and add your project name make sure firestore rules in the firebase account is read write true

Comment: Same error. I don't think the problem resides in FireStore, since I can read and write fine on the database. I think the issue is between the Cloud Function and IoT Core

Comment: Did you enable google clouds computing from cloud ? Do u have default service account ?

Comment: Hey Tasnuva! I've found the solution and posted it below. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great  . Very good to know about this and congratulations for your efforts .